# добавить язык в многоязычный сайт

Tags: php

пока было два языка(основной ru и перевод ua), было все понятно. добавил eng. теперь не могу разобраться с php

```
<!-- Start Interiors -->
            <div class="row">
                <?php 
                    $args = array(
                        'posts_per_page' => 6,
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'category_name' => ($lang == 'ru' ? 'interiors' : 'interiors-ua'),
                        'lang' => $lang,
                    );
```

Comment: `switch ($lang) {
    case "ua":
        $category_name = 'interiors-ua';
        break;
    case "eng":
        $category_name = 'interiors-eng';
        break;
    default:
       $category_name = 'interiors';
}`
как вариант

Comment: пробовал. не решает проблемы (хотя, возможно не туда влепил). кто может поработать с сайтом на предмет многоязычности и плавающего меню дайте знать